# Why can I throw an exception after a return statement?

Tags: c#

The C# compiler seems to not care if I have a `throw` statement after a `return` statement, even if the `throw` is quite clearly unreachable. The opposite is not true: the compiler can detect a `return` after a `throw` to be unreachable. Is this a compiler defect?

This compiles fine:

```
string MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return "";
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}

string MyMethod()
{
    return "";
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

This will not compile, failing on the `return` statements:

```
string MyOtherProperty
{
    get
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
        return "";
    }
}

string MyOtherMethod()
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
    return "";
}
```

EDIT: this is with .NET 4.5.1, C# version 5.0.

EDIT 2: This is the warning I see when compiling the second option (throw before return): `Unreachable code detected`

Comment: what version of the compiler?

Comment: this happens in my compiler as well: target framework .net 4.5.1, C#5, VS 2013 Professional

Comment: Do you get compiler _warnings_ or _errors_?

Comment: Compiler warns when there are unreachable code in the method. In case when the `return` is unreachable it more that unreachable because not all code paths returns the value.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan but throwing an exception breaks the execution anyway.

Comment: @Selman22, yes you are right.

Comment: Second implementation also compiles with warning "Unreachable code detected". Probably you may have code analysis rules in place which may be flagging warning as error.

Comment: Please include all actual compiler messages instead of "it fails".

Comment: @CodeCaster Done. Regardless, that warning is not the issue here - the real question is why doesn't it detect the dead code in the first example.